# PHP: Can't unserialise php object that now implements the \Serializable interface

Tags: php, serialization

According to [the docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php)

> when an old instance of a class that implements this interface now, which had been serialized before the class implemeted the interface, is unserialized, __wakeup() is called instead of the unserialize method, which might be useful for migration purposes.

I thought that's quite clever and useful and wanted to check it out. Unfortunately it didn't work for me and I wonder whether there's something I'm doing wrong or whether there's a bug.

Test code:

```
//class Foo
class Foo implements \Serializable
{
    public $a = 'lorem';

    public function __wakeup()
    {
        fprintf(STDOUT, "in %s\n", __METHOD__);
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        fprintf(STDOUT, "in %s\n", __METHOD__);

        return serialize([
            $this->a,
        ]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        fprintf(STDOUT, "in %s\n", __METHOD__);

        list(
            $this->a,
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}

//$foo = new Foo();
//var_dump(serialize($foo));
//exit;

$serialised = 'O:3:"Foo":1:{s:1:"a";s:5:"lorem";}';
//$serialised = 'C:3:"Foo":22:{a:1:{i:0;s:5:"lorem";}}';

$foo = unserialize($serialised);
var_dump($foo);
```

It crashes with:

```
Warning: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Foo' in /in/SHaCP on line 39
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 13 of 34 bytes in /in/SHaCP on line 39
bool(false)
```

In essence, I serialised the `$foo` object without and with the `\Serializable` interface. Then added the interface and tried to `unserialize()` the object serialised in the previous form (note that the serialised string starting with `O` is without the interface, while the one starting with `C` is with the interface).

Is there something I'm doing wrong here? Or maybe I misunderstood the docs?

Interestingly, the code [runs fine on hhvm at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/SHaCP#output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That IS the MAIN difference between default serialization and one from the interface - by default it serializes the entire object, but with implementation of interface you define how to serialize already created object' attributes.

As such, the resulting string is going to be different due to internal implementation - as you can see in one case it's starting with "O", and in the other it's "C". Because of that you'll have to do saving of it again.

Comment: The docs I referred to say that I don't need to save it again if I add the interface to my class. The docs say it would automagically call `__wakeup()` instead of `unserialize()` in that case. Are you trying to say the docs are wrong?

Comment: It does not say that it would work this way, it only talks about migration.You may have noticed the second comment about the issue you are experiencing now. You may use the example given by Olivier to adapt to your needs given that you know for which classes to add it to.

Comment: Could you provide me with a link to the second comment I may have noticed, please? If you mean [this comment](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php#122259), then it says that it should work exactly how I explained (and how the docs explain). The [comment from Olivier](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php#115019) isn't related to what I'm describing here.

I've read the docs excerpt I quoted again 10 times slowly and it still seems to me like php is supposed to call `__wakeup()` instead of `unserialize()` in my case.

Comment: I read [this comment](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php#122259) again and realised the commenter specifically used inheritance to achieve the "backward compatible" behaviour. I'm not sure whether he used inheritance just to prove something or whether it was absolutely necessary for the solution to work. If using inheritance is necessary, then I'd say the docs are incomplete -- it should have specifically mentioned that inheritance must be used to handle BC. I'll keep this question open for a while and accept your answer if no one else has anything more to add.

Comment: You might try adding a comment on PHP page or opening an issue in their groups. It’s not an obvious thing and would be worthwhile.